# LINQ to XML - Unable to read Elements or Descendants from XDocument or XElement

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Given below is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<Students>
  <Student>
    <Ordinal>1</Ordinal>
    <Name>Student1</Name>
    <BirthDate>Date1</BirthDate>
    <ID>ID1</ID>
  </Student>

  <Student>
    <Ordinal>2</Ordinal>
    <Name>Student2</Name>
    <BirthDate>Date2</BirthDate>
    <ID>ID2</ID>
  </Student>
</Students>
```

It's stored locally and loaded:

```
var path = @"C:\Users\Public\Desktop\LINQ - XML\Students.xml";
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(path);
XElement xEl = XElement.Load(path);
```

When I print content of either 'XDoc' or 'xEl' to the console: `Console.WriteLine(xDoc);` I get the full XML file.

But when I try to access (print to console) `xEl.Element("Student")` or `xEl.Descendants("Student")` or `xEl.Elements()` (xDoc also), only thing that gets printed to the console is xContainer info line: `System.Xml.Linq.XContainer+<GetElements>d__39`

Namespaces should not be a problem but I checked them anyways using both and got blanks.

```
XNamespace ns = xEl.GetDefaultNamespace(); // For XElement
XNamespace df = xDoc.Root.Name.Namespace; // For XDocument
```

What would be the way to access those elements?

Comment: `xEl.Element("Student")` works fine for me. For `Descendants` and `Elements`, those methods return a *sequence* - if you iterate over the sequence and print each individual element, I'd expect it to be fine.

Comment: To string is overriden for XNode https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml.Linq/System/Xml/Linq/XLinq.cs,ff949cd50c3ec19c,references. And Element should work. While Descendants won't as it's a collection. Using an helper that have a more powerfull Dump method to display a string serialisation of the collection may be a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have access to those elememts. There is just a missonception on what `Console.WriteLine` does .

`Console.WriteLine`just call `ToString` over the thing.
For `XNode` the `ToString` is overriden to return a Xml string. [source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml.Linq/System/Xml/Linq/XLinq.cs,ff949cd50c3ec19c,references)

It will work for `xEl.Element` as it's return an `XElement`.
`XElement` is a `XContainer`, that is an `XNode`. So XNode overriden method will be called.

But not for Descendants as it return a collection waiting to be enumerated. Lazy linQ.

In order to display your result you can either enumerate the decendants and call `ToString`  on them.

```
foreach(var el in xEl.Descendants("Student")){
    Console.WriteLine(el);
}
```

Here is an Example: [Live Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sbPKuy)

```
var input = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
<Students>
<Student>
<Ordinal>1</Ordinal>
<Name>Student1</Name>
<BirthDate>Date1</BirthDate>
<ID>ID1</ID>
</Student>


<Student>
<Ordinal>2</Ordinal>
<Name>Student2</Name>
<BirthDate>Date2</BirthDate>
<ID>ID2</ID>
</Student>
</Students>";

// Parse string is equivalent to load path. 
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(input);
XElement xEl = XElement.Parse(input);

var xDocString = xDoc.ToString();

var XElElement = xEl.Element("Student").ToString();
// => <Student>  <Ordinal>1</Ordinal> ...

var XElDecendant = xEl.Descendants("Student").ToString();
// => System.Xml.Linq.XContainer+<GetDescendants>d__39
// I'm a linQ container containing XNode, please enumerate me. 


var xDocElement = xDoc.Element("Student").ToString();
//=> null

var xDocDecendant = xDoc.Descendants("Student").ToString();            
// => System.Xml.Linq.XContainer+<GetDescendants>d__39
// I'm a linQ container containing XNode, please enumerate me. 

foreach(var el in xEl.Descendants("Student")){
    Console.WriteLine(el);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Console.WriteLine expects a string. If you pass in an object to this method, the object should override the ToString method, otherwise it will print the fully qualified object name.

Based on your above statement, it looks like the XDocument object overrides the ToString() method to allow the Console to print XML content as a string. If your return type is `System.Xml.Linq.XContainer+<GetElements>` try using LINQ to convert the object and print to the console.

**You can't print the collection of XElements which is an XContainer object. You need to iterate through each XElement and print it.**

The below LINQ query should work:

```
xEl.Elements().ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

Answer (score 0):

to get the first student

```
XDocument data = XDocument.Load("students.xml");
Console.WriteLine(data.Root.Elements().ElementAt(0));
```

to get the node i

```
Console.WriteLine(data.Root.Elements().ElementAt(0).Nodes().ElementAt(i));
```